# (Answerd by self)Swift array returns 0 count in function numberofRows(in tableView but anywhere else it returns correct amount of array.count

Tags: arrays, swift, macos, count, tableview

I have a project that loads JSON file from internet and stores it in an array and a dictionary. When i print the count of the Array or Dict in viewDitload or viewDidDisappear i get a correct count of 50 thats in the JSON file. But in the numberOfRows and objectForValue calls for the tableViewDataSource it returns 0 for the count. i am overlooking something but at opening and closing of window there is information in the array but when the tableView is reloading somehow the array is empty. Here is my code any help is really appreciated

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate {

    var coursesDict = [String: Course]()
    var coursesArray = [Course]()

    @IBAction func refreshTable(_ sender: Any) {
        table.reloadData()
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var table: NSTableView!

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {

        let numOfRows = coursesArray.count
        print(numOfRows)

        return numOfRows

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> Any? {
        return coursesArray[row]
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "courses"),
            let savedCourses = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? [String: Course] {
            self.coursesDict = savedCourses
            loadDataFromURL()

            self.coursesArray = Array(coursesDict.values)
            print(coursesDict.count, " appLaunch")
        } else {
            print("There is an issue")
        }
    }

        override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear() {
        let encodedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: coursesDict)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedData, forKey: "courses")
        print(coursesDict.count, "viewUnload")
    }

    func loadDataFromURL() {
        // Fetch URL
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.apple.com/nl/today/static/data/hub/1101000001001110001.json")!

        // Load Data
        let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)

        // Deserialize JSON
        let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: AnyObject]

        let coursesJSON = json?["courses"] as? [AnyObject]

        for object in coursesJSON! {
            let id = object["id"] as! String
            if coursesDict[id] == nil {
                let name = object["shortName"] as! String
                let program = object["programName"] as! String
                let shortDescription = object["shortDesc"] as! String
                let mediumDescription = object["mediumDesc"] as! String
                let longDescription = object["longDesc"] as! String
                let imageURL = object["image"] as! String

                let tempCourse = Course(id: id, name: name, program: program, shortDescription: shortDescription, mediumDescription: mediumDescription, longDescription: longDescription, imageURL: imageURL)

                coursesDict[id] = tempCourse
            }
        }
        print(coursesDict.count, "loadURL")
    }

}
```

I even have a button on my view that reloads the tableView in case the information is not loaded before the tableView reloads automaticaly

Comment: did you make sure your tableview `dataSource` is connected in your storyboard or nib file?

Comment: Yes when i replace numberofRows with manual return of 5 and objectValue whit manual string "test" they show up in table view. When i test whit print staments i get the correct count every where exept in in both tableSource functions i get 0 returned

Comment: and when you click on the `refreshTable` button, does that populate the table correctly?

Comment: No thats what is so strange. when i close the app the information is in the array when i open the app the information is there. I know its there because i am outputting it to the console. its even there directly after the URLLoad because i can print it there testet it with for in loops on all those places. It's yust not there. even when i print the information before reloading the data with the button in my console ig get a count and directly not a count.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was not i my code. The problem was in the fact that i had two instances of the viewController in my Xib so when i hard coded things in to the array it was working because both instances would have that info but the viewDidload from the second viewcontroller was never calded because it was not connected to to any view

Answer (score 0):

I guess that `numberOfRows` is being called before you retrieve the data from the internet. One way to solve that is by setting a listener in `coursesArray`, try replacing this:

```
var coursesArray: [Course] = []
```

With this:

```
var coursesArray: [Course] = [] {
    didSet {
        table.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking that to but a have a manual reload button to do that and i even put a print statement before the reload and then it returns 50 as it should tableView.reload is directly after that and then its 0. So some where there something happends.

Answer (score 0):

```
func loadDataFromURL() {
        // Fetch URL
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.apple.com/nl/today/static/data/hub/1101000001001110001.json")!

        // Load Data
        let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)

        // Deserialize JSON
        let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: AnyObject]

        let coursesJSON = json?["courses"] as? [AnyObject]

        for object in coursesJSON! {
            let id = object["id"] as! String
            if coursesDict[id] == nil {
                let name = object["shortName"] as! String
                let program = object["programName"] as! String
                let shortDescription = object["shortDesc"] as! String
                let mediumDescription = object["mediumDesc"] as! String
                let longDescription = object["longDesc"] as! String
                let imageURL = object["image"] as! String

                let tempCourse = Course(id: id, name: name, program: program, shortDescription: shortDescription, mediumDescription: mediumDescription, longDescription: longDescription, imageURL: imageURL)

                coursesDict[id] = tempCourse
table.reloadData()
            }
        }
        print(coursesDict.count, "loadURL")
    }

}
```